# How to find number of years between two timestamp dates in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to find the number of years between two timestamp dates in Hive.

This I tried in SQL.

In SQL:

Datediff(year, date1, date2)

But In Hive I tried:

```
Datediff(year(date1), year(date2))
```

But this throws an error stating that

> "cannot recognize input near 'datediff' '(' 'year' in expression specification"

Can someone help me in learning this new thing.

Comment: `extract(year from date2) - extract(year from date1)` will give you the number of year boundaries... don't know if that is required.

Comment: @Sara . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is not obvious how a difference in  years should be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve such results:

**1) Extract & Subtraction**

You can simply extract year from two dates and then perform subtraction on those two values.

```
select abs(extract(year from "2019-01-29") - extract(year from "2020-01-20"));
```

Problem with this approach is it will return you 0 even if you are subtracting first and last day of the same year and will return 1 if your two dates are 31st Dec and 1st Jan, but if that is not harmful for usecase and we just need to see if year changed between two dates then this approach can be useful.

**2) datediff function**

Function will return number of days between startdate and enddate. When you divide that by 365.25 then it will return number of years in decimal places.

```
select datediff('2019-02-01', '2019-01-27')/365.25;
```

You might want to truncate result of above query to two decimal places. If you are looking for an integer number only then just cast it to integer.

```
select cast(datediff('2019-02-01', '2019-01-27')/365.25 as int);
```

**3) months_between function**

This function will return number of months difference between two dates.

```
select abs(cast(months_between('2019-01-10', '2020-01-10')as int));
```

Above query will return 12 as a result. If you want to have result in number of years then you can divide result of above query by 12.

**4) Custom UDF**

This approach is complex then all the above as you need to write your custom UDF function and then validate against all the scenarios.

Write a custom UDF function which takes two dates/strings/timestamps as input and then return difference in years/months/dates/seconds/minutes.

You can write a query also doing the same things using multiple available UDF's in hive.

Here's the link for your reference:
[Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following one :

```
SELECT YEAR(date1)-YEAR(date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If input is string and timestamp, then you can try below

```
hive> select current_timestamp();
OK
2019-01-29 04:57:04.128
hive> select year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-01-29 04:57:04.128', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
OK
2019

hive> select year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2021-01-29 04:57:04.128', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) - year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-01-29 04:57:04.128', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
OK
2
Time taken: 0.054 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an integer, you can do the calculation directly:

```
select (case when date_format(date1, 'MMDD') < date_format(date2, 'MMDD')
             then year(date1) - year(date2) - 1
             else year(date1) - year(date2)
        end)
```

Or you can use an approximation:

```
select datediff(date1, date2) / 365.25
```