# Hive: Calculate exactly 1 year from date in format 'yyyy-MM-dd' string

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

I need to calculate if has passed exactly 1 year or more from this date '2021-01-29', in HIVE.
So the result date must be in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format, and equal to '2022-01-29' or later. '2022-01-28' it's not correct answer.

It's possible to use `date_add('2021-01-29', interval 1 year)`, if so, could someone explain how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Hive since 1.2.0 you can **add interval** to the date:

```
select date('2021-01-29') + interval 1 year
```

Result:

```
2022-01-29
```

For old version of hive use this recipe:

1 Year = 12 months. Add 12 months using add_months function:

```
select add_months('2021-01-29',12)
```

Result:

```
2022-01-29
```

If you want to add more than one year, multiply 12 by the number of years.

Comment: Many thanks @leftjoin. Regarding my 2nd question, do you think it if it's possible to use date_add() with the INTERVAL clause?

How could I check if diference between two dates is >= 1 year?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO No. and no such need. interval can be added to date without any function like in my answer

Comment: Ok @leftjoin. can you show me please, how could I check if diference between two dates is >= 1 year?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO select MONTHS_BETWEEN('2022-01-29','2021-01-29') /12 >=1 --returns true

Comment: My problem @leftjoin is that with Months_Between `select MONTHS_BETWEEN('2022-01-29','2021-01-25') /12 >=1;` also returns true, and it's not correct. Can you help please?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO it was already asked before and all possible solutions are here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54419266/2700344

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin. I already saw the link you posted, but all solutions presented there are not accurate. They all show that between '2021-01-25' and '2022-01-29' has already passed an year. But even `select (abs(cast(months_between('2022-01-29','2021-01-25')as int)/12));` and `select cast(datediff('2022-01-29', '2021-01-25')/365.25 as int);` both return (1 year).

`select ('2021-01-29' <= to_date(add_months('2022-01-29',-12)));` returns true, it's accurate but doesn't do calculation between dates in years.

Thank you very much.
Do you know someone that could help, please?